# Uncaught exception in Promise all

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm receiving uncaught exception while executing following code. It fails, when i try to create promise which rejects automatically.

It works if I set a small timeout before rejecting promise.

```js
function emptyPromise(fail) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  if (fail) {
   reject({
    status: -20,
    responseText: {
     reason: 'Empty promise',
     success: false
    }
   });
  } else {
   resolve();
  }
 });
}

var arr = [emptyPromise(true)];
Promise.all(arr).then(function(){}).catch(function(e){console.log(e);})
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the exception. I just copy/pasted your code and ran it using Node 10.x and it produced the correct response.

Comment: Code seems fine. Can you paste exception error ?

Comment: Hey, here is an image: [link](http://prntscr.com/nxs8qf). It seems that I'm receiving promise rejection, which is uncaught, but I would want to catch that in... well 'catch' block.

Comment: can you paste exception error, image you added doesn't help

Comment: There is no other exception written in console. It's just dev tools that catch this exception, when 'Pause on exception' is checked.

Comment: @JernejHabjan Well, then simply uncheck that option if you don't want the debugger to pause? There is no uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an solution, which doesn't throw Exception in chrome dev tools even when checking 'Pause on exception'.

```
function emptyPromise(fail) {
    return Promise.reject('rere');
}
emptyPromise(true).catch(function(){console.log(arguments)})
```

This [static promise reject method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject#Using_the_static_Promise.reject()_method) saved me a ton.
When creating empty promise, make them with Promise.resolve(...) and Promise.reject(...).